# Pandas: how to efficiently filter data based on their frequency

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data-frame  with three columns, follower, user, and ratio.

For every unique element in u, I would like to know how many times, it occurred and remove the rows corresponding to elements that occur less than say 5 times. Here is my code, it is inefficient. I would like to know how to properly write it.

```
known_follower_id= np.unique(following_df.follower.values) # IDs of members of the list in the saved database
userid, counts = np.unique(following_df.user.values, return_counts= True) # ID of people they followed in the saved database
count_idx=np.argsort(-counts) # number of times a user was followed
trimmed_following_df= following_df.copy(deep= True)

th = 5
idx_th = counts< th

userid_removed = userid[idx_th]
idx_userid_rem= [i for i,v in enumerate(trimmed_following_df.user.values) if v in userid_removed]

trimmed_following_df=trimmed_following_df.drop(idx_userid_rem)
```

Comment: Can you please post a sample dataset and the desired output. I think I got the question but want to be sure the output is matching the ask.

Answer (score 0):

In lieu of data, here's how I would do it. See if this helps you get what you want.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'follower': ['John', 'Jane', 'Jack', 'Suzy', 'Kate', 'Mark', 'Alex', 'Boby', 'Cris', 'Duke'],
    'user':     ['milk', 'milk', 'milk', 'milk', 'milk', 'milk', 'pear', 'pear', 'wire', 'silk'],
    'ratio':    [.4, .4, .5, .2, .6, .3, .5, .8, .9, .2]})
print (df)

df['usercount'] = df['user'].map(df['user'].value_counts())

df = df[df['usercount'] > 5]
df.drop(columns=['usercount'],inplace=True)
print (df)
```

The output of this will be:

**Original dataframe:**

```
  follower  user  ratio
0     John  milk    0.4
1     Jane  milk    0.4
2     Jack  milk    0.5
3     Suzy  milk    0.2
4     Kate  milk    0.6
5     Mark  milk    0.3
6     Alex  pear    0.5
7     Boby  pear    0.8
8     Cris  wire    0.9
9     Duke  silk    0.2
```

**Updated dataframe:**

```
  follower  user  ratio
0     John  milk    0.4
1     Jane  milk    0.4
2     Jack  milk    0.5
3     Suzy  milk    0.2
4     Kate  milk    0.6
5     Mark  milk    0.3
```